# horizontal dragable bar inclusion in mpchart graphs?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a way to add a horizontal drag-able bar over the charts, graphs.
I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
The purpose of the bar is to add a limiter.

Pointing to an already asked question will also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you found any solution yet????

Comment: Sorry for the delay. i haven't